# Luks encryption block name format

Tags: linux, unix, centos-7, disk-encryption, luks

After disk encryption with LUKS I have chacked my disk with lsblk and found the bellow output. Here the luks  id luks-95a00a58-7a6f-429a-a45f-02308d9b1b28 is not familiar to me . What is the meaning of this format "luks-95a00a58-7a6f-429a-a45f-02308d9b1b28"

```
[subarno@test-1 ~]$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0   15G  0 disk  

  ├─sda1                                          8:1    0    1G  0 part  /boot

  └─sda2                                          8:2    0   14G  0 part  

     └─luks-95a00a58-7a6f-429a-a45f-02308d9b1b28 253:0    0   14G  0 crypt
          ├─centos_test--1-root                     253:1    0 12.5G   0 lvm   /

          └─centos_test--1-swap                     253:2    0  1.5G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                                            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom   
[subarno@test-1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The “luks-” prefix marks the partition as encrypted using LUKS. The rest is a [Universally Unique Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or UUID, commonly used to, you guessed it, uniquely identify one thing (in this case an encrypted partition) of potentially many.